# FontExplorer like application for Windows

Tags: windows, software-rec, fonts

Has anybody found a font browser solution as great as FontExplorer on Mac, for Windows?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doubtful, there's always [Opicon](http://opcion.sourceforge.net/), which is open source and written in Java if you're looking for something free.

However, I recommend you look at the answers provided at "[What is the best (free) Font Explorer ...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/301982/what-is-the-best-free-font-explorer-for-windows)" question @ SO.

Comment: I try to stay away from Java based apps :)

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Fonts Explorer 3.6.2](http://www.softpedia.com/get/Others/Font-Utils/Windows-Fonts-Explorer.shtml) ([Screenshots](http://www.softpedia.com/progScreenshots/Windows-Fonts-Explorer-Screenshot-47303.html))

This was [recently endorsed by the Lifehacker blog](http://lifehacker.com/5231061/windows-fonts-explorer-displays-and-manages-your-windows-fonts) as well.

There's also NexusFont, hosted at [xiles.net](http://xiles.net).

Answer (score 1):

**[AMP Font Viewer](http://www.ampsoft.net/utilities/FontViewer.php)** is a **free** program that features stuff like:

- Being able to type up a test sample to see how it will render in the font
- Install/uninstall of fonts from your computer
- Allows you to group fonts for easy reference. E.g. You have a go to set for particular jobs, you can group them all and quick pull them up to flick through
- Screen list of the fonts you have installed with the names in their respective typefaces

Answer (score 0):

I use [Suitcase for Windows](http://www.extensis.com/en/products/font_management/product_information.jsp?id=1055). It has all I need and an excellent InDesign and Illustrator integration.

I also tried [FontExpert](http://www.proximasoftware.com/fontexpert/). It has a lot of features but the UI is a little bloated.

Answer (score 0):

Old question I know - but it came up again and was redirected to here, and I've got one to add that isn't on the lists.

I've been using "The Font Thing" by a woman named Sue Fisher for years.  Not sure if it's like "FontExplorer" but it's handy for viewing multiple fonts, as well as organizing and installing/uninstalling sets of fonts.

And it's free. :)  It was last updated in 1999 but never really needed any more added to it (for my needs anyway).

http://members.ozemail.com.au/~scef/tft.html

I don't think I've tested it with anything newer than XP myself, but I would be surprised if it didn't work in Vista and 7.